# Trying to pass a function as an argument to a timer, unresolved linker error

Tags: c++, templates

I am just starting out c++, and am trying to pass a function that I want to be repeated to a timer that is supposed to trigger it. I am attempting to use templates to achieve this, but keep getting LNK2019 error stating that I have unresolved externals.

Main class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "TimerClass.h"
#include "Functions.h"

int main()
{
    TimerClass timer = TimerClass(1000);
    timer.startTimer(1000, [&]() {
                std::cout << "This function should be called everytime the interval is met" <<  std::endl;
            });
    while (true) 
    {
        
    }
}
```

TimerClass .h-file:

```
#pragma once
#include "Windows.h"
#include <thread>

class TimerClass
{
private:
    bool timerOn = false;
public:
    double time = 0;
public:
    double interval;

public:
    TimerClass(double interval);

public:
    template<typename Function>
    void startTimer(Function func);
public:
    template<typename Function>
    void startTimer(double interval, Function func);

};
```

TimerClass.cpp-file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "TimerClass.h"
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

TimerClass::TimerClass(double interval)
{
    this->interval = interval;
}

template<typename Function>
void TimerClass::startTimer(Function func)
{
    startTimer(this->interval, func);
}

template<typename Function>
void TimerClass::startTimer(double interval, Function func)
{
    std::thread t([=]()
        {
            timerOn = true;
            int passedMilliseconds = 0;
            int intervalInt = interval;
            this->interval = interval;
            while (timerOn)
            {
                Sleep(1);
                time += 0.001;
                passedMilliseconds++;
                if (passedMilliseconds % intervalInt == 0)
                {
                    func();
                }

            }
        });
    t.detach();
}
```

Here is the error message:

> Timer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall TimerClass::startTimer<class <lambda_fde307b262397283ec53dcbc4a2ba1b4> >(double,class <lambda_fde307b262397283ec53dcbc4a2ba1b4>)" (??$startTimer@V<lambda_fde307b262397283ec53dcbc4a2ba1b4>@@@TimerClass@@QAEXNV<lambda_fde307b262397283ec53dcbc4a2ba1b4>@@@Z) referenced in function _main
> 1>C:\Users\matia\source\repos\Timer\Debug\Timer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: You must implement templated code in the included header files. Also as a side note, C++ is not Java or C# you don't have to write public: or private: before every method and member :D When you write public: all the following members and methods are public until the next specifier. Same goes for private and protected of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header .H file needs to implement all templated methods like this:

```
class TimerClass
{
private:
    bool timerOn = false;

public:
    double time = 0;
    double interval;

    TimerClass(double interval);

    template<typename Function>
    void startTimer(Function func)
    {
        startTimer(this->interval, func);
    }

    template<typename Function>
    void startTimer(double interval, Function func)
    {
        std::thread t([=]()
        {
            timerOn = true;
            int passedMilliseconds = 0;
            int intervalInt = interval;
            this->interval = interval;
            while (timerOn)
            {
                Sleep(1);
                time += 0.001;
                passedMilliseconds++;
                if (passedMilliseconds % intervalInt == 0)
                {
                    func();
                }

            }
        });
        t.detach();
    }

};
```

What can remain in the .CPP source file is the constructor.
Also I removed the duplicated public and private specifiers.